# Php move_uploaded_file returning base_dir restriction on source file

Tags: php

I am trying to make a image uploader. I have searched the Web but found no working answer. It always throws error when I call move_uploaded_file. It says that the source path has base_dir restriction although the documentation says:

> However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to
>   allow the moving of uploaded files in which filename may conflict with
>   such restrictions.

The code:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['uploader']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif")
    throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported format! Supported formats are jpg, png, gif.");

$filepath = "/home/iv0113/public_html/data/uploads/images/" . md5($_FILES['uploader']['tmp_name']) . "." . $extension;
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploader']['tmp_name'], $filepath))
    throw new RuntimeException("Error uploading file!");
```

The error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpaG1OIW) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/iv0113/) in /hd2/home/iv0113/public_html/php/photos_functions.php on line 44

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpaG1OIW) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/iv0113/) in /hd2/home/iv0113/public_html/php/photos_functions.php on line 44

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/tmp/phpaG1OIW): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /hd2/home/iv0113/public_html/php/photos_functions.php on line 44

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpaG1OIW' to '/home/iv0113/public_html/data/uploads/images/7a2b480c131000161369ca009260c0d4.jpg' in /hd2/home/iv0113/public_html/php/photos_functions.php on line 44
```

Comment: you need to set you own temp. the server temp is not available to you,. see: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: `/home/iv0113` is not the same as `/hd2/home/iv0113` as well...

Comment: what do you mean by 'set your own temp'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the destination directory didn't have the right permissions.